# Error while upgrade in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

I am getting this result by running `sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up udev (225-1ubuntu9.1) ...
addgroup: The group `input' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
insserv: warning: script 'K07fruhod' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'fruhod' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service rc.local if started
insserv: There is a loop between service rc.local and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting fruhod depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service cgproxy at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 4
insserv: There is a loop between service rc.local and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 3
insserv: There is a loop between service fruhod and mountkernfs if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service fruhod if started
insserv:  loop involving service fruhod at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop between service fruhod and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?

Comment: after typing the above command i am getting this

Comment: Please paste the complete command and result. You said you get this after running `sudo apt-get upgrade` but in the last comment, you say you get it after running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`!! Which one is the command you use?

Comment: after typing sudo apt-get upgrade i am getting above mentioned result

Comment: The issue appears to be that fruhod is broken. Remove that script from your /etc/init.d.